# Conditionally replace values based on content of subsequent row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that lists people's daily activities in order of time. The first activity of the day (begining at midnight) has been called "Start", and usually preceeds waking (Wake), but not always. For each person (group_by(id)), I would like to replace "Start" with the word "Sleep" if "Start" preceeds "Wake". But if "Start" does not preceed "Wake", as for id 22, then I would like to retain "Start"

```
id <- c(11,11,11,11,22,22,22,22,22,22,33,33,33)
activity <-c("Start","Wake","TV","Eat","Start","TV","Sleep","Wake","Eat","Dressed","Start","Wake","BrushTeeth")
DF<- data.frame(id,activity)
DF
   id   activity
1  11      Start
2  11       Wake
3  11         TV
4  11        Eat
5  22      Start
6  22         TV
7  22      Sleep
8  22       Wake
9  22        Eat
10 22    Dressed
11 33      Start
12 33       Wake
13 33 BrushTeeth
```

This is what I'd like the final data to look like (notice "Start" in row 1 and row 7 has been replaced by "Sleep", but remains "Start" in row 5 because it does not preceed "Wake")

```
   id   activity
1  11      Sleep
2  11       Wake
3  11         TV
4  11        Eat
5  22      Start
6  22         TV
7  22      Sleep
8  22       Wake
9  22        Eat
10 22    Dressed
11 33      Sleep
12 33       Wake
13 33 BrushTeeth
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
library(dplyr)

 DF %>% 
   mutate(new = replace(activity, activity == 'Start' & lead(activity) == 'Wake', 'Sleep'))
```

which gives,

> ```
>    id   activity        new
> 1  11      Start      Sleep
> 2  11       Wake       Wake
> 3  11         TV         TV
> 4  11        Eat        Eat
> 5  22      Start      Start
> 6  22         TV         TV
> 7  22      Sleep      Sleep
> 8  22       Wake       Wake
> 9  22        Eat        Eat
> 10 22    Dressed    Dressed
> 11 33      Start      Sleep
> 12 33       Wake       Wake
> 13 33 BrushTeeth BrushTeeth
> ```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table` would be to specify the `i` with logical condition and assign (`:=`) the activity for those rows returning TRUE from the `i` to 'Sleep'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[activity == 'Start' & shift(activity, type = 'lead') == 'Wake',
        activity := 'Sleep'][]  

DF
#    id   activity
# 1: 11      Sleep
# 2: 11       Wake
# 3: 11         TV
# 4: 11        Eat
# 5: 22      Start
# 6: 22         TV
# 7: 22      Sleep
# 8: 22       Wake
# 9: 22        Eat
#10: 22    Dressed
#11: 33      Sleep
#12: 33       Wake
#13: 33 BrushTeeth
```